# Search for decimal 250 in NotSupportedException in Code

Tags: c#, exception

I want to see if my C# Error (Exception) code contains the number 250, but it isn't working.

```
if (Divide < RESULT_MINVALUE)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

else if (Divide > RESULT_MAXVALUE) //RESULT_MAXVALUE is an const public decimal = 250
{
    throw new NotSupportedException()
    {
        if (NotSupportedException.ToString.Contains("250")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Everything's fine");
        }

        else Console.WriteLine("Programm ERROR");
    }

}

else return Divide;
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do here and your code would not even compile.

Comment: exactly what are you trying to do? what is it that isn't working?

Comment: I want to see if the Error wich would exist if there wasnt an exception Contains the number 250 so I am abel to see if my Code works, (in the console, or in a string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are after is something like this:

```
else if (Divide > RESULT_MAXVALUE) //RESULT_MAXVALUE is an const public decimal = 250
        {
            if (RESULT_MAXVALUE == 250)
                Console.WriteLine("Everything's fine");
            else 
                throw new NotSupportedException()
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add 'Divide' value to the raised NotSupportedException in order to check if that value is in the exception when you catch it, something like:

```
if (Divide < RESULT_MINVALUE)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(Divide.ToString());
    }
```